# Parse txt file with shell

Tags: html, shell, parsing

I have a txt file containing the output from several commands executed on a networking equipment. I wanted to parse this txt file so i can sort and print on an HTML page.

What is the best/easiest way to do this? Export every command to an array and then print array with sort on the HTML code?

Commands are between lines and they're tabular data. example:

```
*********************************************************************
# command 1
*********************************************************************

Object                               column1  column2   Total
-------------------------------------------------------------------
object 1                              526    9484       10010
object 2                              2      10008      10010
Object 3                              0      20000      20000


*********************************************************************
# command 2
*********************************************************************
(... tabular data ...)
```

Can someone suggest any code or file where see how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mind doing it in e.g. Python?

Comment: Do you want to extract only the lines containing commands and then sort the commands alphabetically?   Or, do you want to include the tabular data?  Or, what?  Do the command lines always start with `#`?

Comment: Hi @John1024.i want to print the tabular data on a HTML table and sort the TOTAL column in descending order. I would prefer shell scripting but in case its much easier with Perl or Python its the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done in Python with this example code:

```
f = open('input.txt')
rulers = 0
table = []
for line in f.readlines():
    if '****' in line:
        rulers += 1
        if rulers == 2:
            table = []
        elif rulers > 2:
            print(table)
            rulers = 0
        continue
    if line == '\n' or '----' in line or line.startswith('#'):
        continue
    table.append(line.split())

print(table)
```

It just prints list of lists of the tabular values. But it can be formatted to whatever HTML or another format you need.

Answer (score 0):

Import into your spreadsheet software.  Export to HTML from there, and modify as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Brad. im automating a process so my intention is to use shell. :)

Comment: @Frosa You can certainly automate your spreadsheet software from the command line.  That's what I would do if I didn't know any programming languages.  In any case, you didn't even tell us what shell or OS you're using.  Your question belongs over at http://www.superuser.com.